# Bottle python data from form into sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, bottle

I want to move data from a form into sqlite3:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/reg/')
@app.route('/reg', methods='POST')
def registration():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('trainsdb2.db')
    c=conn.cursor()
    name = request.forms.get('name', default=False)
    #surname = request.forms.get('surname', default=False)
    #mail = request.forms.get('mail', default=False)
    #adress = request.forms.get('adress', default=False)
    #login_def = request.forms.get('login_defined', default=False)

    #password_def = request.forms.get('password_defined', default=False)
    c.execute('INSERT INTO LoginData (id,login,password) VALUES("%s","%s","%s")'%(random.randint(1,1000),name,'b'))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return template('index')
```

My sqlite3 table was created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE LoginData (id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, login varchar NOT NULL, password varchar NOT NULL, "loggedin" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', "randStri" varchar, PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="/reg" method="post">
<table><tr>
  <td><b>Name: </b></td><td><input name="name" type="text"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>Surname: </b></td><td><input name="surname" type="text"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>Email: </b></td><td><input name="mail" type="text"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>Adress: </b></td><td><input name="adress" type="text"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>Login: </b></td><td><input name="login_defined" type="text"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>Password: </b></td><td><input name="password_defined" type="password"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b><input value="Register!" type="submit"></b></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

When i put my data into the html form in my 'login' field in my database i have a '**False**', always, regardless of what i have placed in this html form. What is the reason for that?

I do not think I am violating any constraints imposed on the database.

One row from my database looks as bellow:
[image]

**EDIT:** After changing default value to: `forms.get('name', default="Missing 'name' in forms.")` I can see that no value is being passed however the question is why it is happening?

**EDIT2:** I have login pages as well code is the following, this part works without any hesitation:

```
@app.route('/login')
@app.route('/login/')
@app.route('/login', method='POST')
def login():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('trainsdb2.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    loginName = request.forms.get('login_name', default=False)
    password = request.forms.get('password', default=False)
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM LoginData WHERE login="%s" AND password="%s"' %(loginName,password))
    if c.fetchone() is not None: 
        response.set_cookie("user", loginName, secret=secretKey)
        log.info = ('not none')
        conn.commit()
        conn.close() 
        redirect('/index')
        return True
    else:
        conn.commit()
        conn.close() 
        return template('login')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close() 
    return template('login')
```

Any ideas? Answers?

Comment: I know that i have auto increment but still sqlite accepts this insert, problem is with login column (second to the left).

Comment: That form is going to the login route, not registration (reg).

Comment: OK but still does not affect database insert.

Comment: Try printing *name* variable and see what console shows. While I know nothing of `bottle` it appears *False* is being inserted.

Comment: But what if this false is generated inside the database itself? Due to violation of some restrictions or whatever.

Comment: Your `False` value comes from `forms.get('name', default=False)`. Item `'name'` does not exist in `forms`. Better use `forms.get('name', default="Missing 'name' in forms.")`

Comment: You mean that I should not specify `name="name"` in forms? Because I have a line `<td><b>Name: </b></td><td><input name="name" type="text"></td></tr>`. OK now I know that the `'name"` is missing. But the question is why

Comment: What is the unseen here? Is there client-side programming? Are any of the other vars sent properly? On the face of it, this should work.

Comment: No client-side programming. There is login page which works just fine (added it to the body)

Comment: Any ideas? What could be improved/changed?